# How to use LSTM for time series with the output as a sequence and not the future values

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, keras, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq

Currently, I have data of batteries and this data is recorded every second for different dates. So, I have data for 10 dates and the output that I need to predict is Zimg and Zreal, which are two features to plot the Nyquist curve for the batteries and it will always be 75 values respectively for these features and these are associated with each of these dates.

So, I have to make use of 9 time-series data frames and 9 target data frames and predict the target data frame for the 10th series time-series data. I have seen many documents where the output is just a future prediction of the time series but not a sequence of data but I am not sure how to apply LSTM for this case when the output is a sequence. Any help would be appreciated.